# ZeroTier connection for ESXi hosts

Tags: networking, vmware, vsphere

i am trying to put my vspehre lab into ZeroTier network. Unfortunately i am failing at it.

Here is want i want to achieve:

```
Internet -> HOME -> Router/VM with ZeroTierApp installed -> Esxi 
   |
ZT BUBBLE
   |
INTERNET -> HOME -> Router/VM with ZeroTierApp installed -> Esxi
```

Management/vmotion inside ZT network.

Basically i have 2 labs , one at home, and one at my friend's home. I would like the VirtualCenter and those 2 host be in the same network(mgmt,vmotion). Clearly i can't install it on ESXi, but it's possible to install it on OpenWRT or in a linux VM.

As far as i understand, i create z ZT network let's say: 192.168.0.0/24 (for esxi MGMT/VC). Then  i  need the ESXi kernel to have ip 192.168.0.10/24 for example, and should be able to contact other devices in 192.168.0.0/24 network utilizing a device in front that would bridge this network with him.

Any idea how to do this ? I tried some tutorials but was failing at them. Any help /ideas would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

ZeroTier works practically like a real Ethernet connection (with ZeroTier acting as a switch), so all concepts should be the same. Among them:

For the ESXi host, having an IP address out of the ZeroTier subnet only makes sense if it is *directly attached* to that subnet. In other words, it only makes sense if the router/VM actually *bridges* the ZeroTier (zt0) interface with the ESXi-facing LAN interface... and the same is done at the other lab.

Normally this would be a poor solution, since it would mean both your homes actually end up sharing a single giant subnet – their DHCP servers would conflict with each other, and it'd be a mess.

However, it would work just fine if both home labs have a dedicated VLAN running from ESXi to the ZeroTier node. You can bridge that VLAN to zt0 without affecting the main network.

If you don't have VLANs, the other (and probably **preferred**) solution would be routing. Instead of creating any bridges, let each ESXi host keep its "normal" (non-ZT) address, and configure *routes* in each ESXi system, or in your LAN's default gateway, for destination <opposite_LAN>/24 via <the_ZT_router>.